# Running `cp` with the `-n` flag in `npm postinstall` blows up the script

Tags: node.js, npm

Not sure why but running `bower install && cp -n .env.settings.sample .env.settings && cp -n .env.private.sample .env.private` as the value for `postinstall` in `package.json` blows up in NPM, whereas running the script without the `-n` flag works fine. It's a valid UNIX command so I'm not sure what's going on here, thanks.

Error log:

```
60 info lifecycle NodeTube@1.0.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
61 verbose stack Error: NodeTube@1.0.0 postinstall: `bower install && cp -n .env.settings.sample .env.settings && cp .env.private.sample .env.private`
61 verbose stack Exit status 1
61 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
61 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
61 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
61 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
61 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
61 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
61 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
61 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
61 verbose stack From previous event:
61 verbose stack     at runAction (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:74:13)
61 verbose stack     at actions.(anonymous function) (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:50:17)
61 verbose stack     at execAction (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:191:18)
61 verbose stack     at withInit (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:108:12)
61 verbose stack From previous event:
61 verbose stack     at withInit (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:175:13)
61 verbose stack     at doOne (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:107:10)
61 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
61 verbose stack     at LOOP (/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
61 verbose stack     at /Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:18:7
61 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
61 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
61 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
62 verbose pkgid NodeTube@1.0.0
63 verbose cwd /Users/anthony/Development/test1/nodetube
64 verbose Darwin 18.5.0
65 verbose argv "/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node" "/Users/anthony/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/npm" "install"
66 verbose node v8.17.0
67 verbose npm  v6.13.4
68 error code ELIFECYCLE
69 error errno 1
70 error NodeTube@1.0.0 postinstall: `bower install && cp -n .env.settings.sample .env.settings && cp .env.private.sample .env.private`
70 error Exit status 1
71 error Failed at the NodeTube@1.0.0 postinstall script.
71 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
72 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: npm utilizes `sh` as the default shell on _*nix_ and not `bash`. Perhaps try providing the `cp -n ...` commands as a  string to  `bash -c`. For instance try with your `postinstall` script defined as: `"postinstall": "bower install && bash -c \"cp -n .env.settings.sample .env.settings && cp -n .env.private.sample .env.private\""`

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work @RobC

Comment: That's weird. **1)** Which OS are you running? **2)** Presumably running `cp -n .env.settings.sample .env.settings && cp -n .env.private.sample .env.private` directly via your commandline works ? **3)** Does running `man cp` show that the `-n` option is supported on your OS? **4)** What is your [script-shell](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config.html#script-shell) set to, i.e. what does running `npm config get script-shell` return? - _(probably best to `edit` your post to provide these answers/details)_

Comment: OS X, yes, yes, null

Comment: I am so close with the `cpy` cli function but it does not work:`cpy .env.settings.sample ./. --rename .env.settings` if you know that API. can't specify cwd

Comment: Seems odd that `script-shell` returns _null._ Try **1)** Run `which bash` _(it prpbably returns `/bin/bash`)_ **2)** Then `cd` to project directory and set npm's script-shell  to value of what step one returns, i.e. `npm config set script-shell "<insert_path_from_step_1_here>"`

Comment: Honestly @RobC I lost a lot of time with this dumb thing I found a solution and am moving on will maybe double back later but I've lost too much time with this already

Comment: Sure, no worries. If you don't resolve the issue consider utilizing [`copyfiles`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) in your npm script, i.e. use _node.js_ instead.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm doing and it's working fine. Ty